# Omit a delimiter type "|," in a row during SQL output

Tags: excel, bash, csv, sqlite, tr

I run a report on an sqlite3 database.

The command is:

```
sqlite3 db.sqlite3 "select job_title, job_url, regions.region_name from job_results join regions on (regions.i_region=job_results.region_id)" > output.csv
```

This produces an output with `|` and `,` delimiters. That is why sometimes, in the first row, because this is a title of a listing, the delimiter type is in the title, so when I open the file using LibreOffice or Excel, part of the first row in a given column is now on the second 2 and all other items are off on that column.

I need to know how to make the output.csv file open in Excel or LibreOffice and not parse the first row because the lister included the delimiter type in their listing title. So, I would want to know how to change the "delimiter" or the `|` or `,` characters in the first row of the csv file only to fix this problem. I tried using `tr '\|' ''` to get rid of those delimiters, but it replaces all of the delimiters I need to keep.

Thank you!

Comment: Can't you use `As`? `Select job_title As \"Job | , Title\"` so it's wrapped in quotes and won't be parsed as a delimiter?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to remove all the `|` and `,` characters from the first line of a file (output.csv), use the below `sed` command and redirect your output to a finished file (finish.csv):

```
sed "1s/[|\,,]//g" output.csv > finish.csv
```

Example initial data (output.csv):

```
ewqweqwe|qwew,eqwe|qwew,ewqe|qweqw,wqeq|
gggggggg|fgggggggg|ggggggggg|gsefsfsfdf|
eqweqweq|aeweqweqw|aweewqweq|adqweqweqe|
```

Example modified data (finish.csv):

```
ewqweqweqweweqweqwewewqeqweqwwqeq
gggggggg|fgggggggg|ggggggggg|gsefsfsfdf|
eqweqweq|aeweqweqw|aweewqweq|adqweqweqe|
```

HTH

Comment: What does `HTH` mean, on StackOverflow it's usually not custom to sign your answers because they are signed by your flair

Comment: Thanks for clarifying :-)

Answer (score 0):

To remove all `|` and `,` in first row, you can pipe this sed to your `sqlite3` command :

```
sqlite3 db.sqlite3 "your_query" | sed '1s/[,|]//g' > output.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

To get a proper CSV file (even with proper quoting if some field has commas), tell `sqlite3` to generate a CSV file:

```
sqlite3 -csv db.sqlite3 "select ..." > output.csv
```